# Safely back up a drive before sending it to data recovery lab (deleted files, not damaged drive)

Tags: 18.04, backup, data-recovery, tar

On Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS Bionic Beaver, I accidentally ran a bash script that uses `rm -rf` in places and accidentally deleted a bunch of directories. I am aware of `extundelete`, however I am sending it straight to data recovery specialists since I don't want to mess anything up further.

I want to back up the drive before sending it out.

How can I safely back up the drive to a separate empty drive by mounting both drives from a live environment, so that no write operations take place on the source drive?

Is `tar` safe in this case?

Comment: You can use clonezilla.

Comment: ok so clonezilla will not do any writes on the source drive at all right?

Comment: No, it just creates an image of the disk that you can clone to another disk, doesn't write the source disk. Although the target disk has to be the same size or larger than the source drive. But may somebody post a better solution :)

Comment: ok thank you. I was just not aware if any writes go on in the background or not. Appriate the clarification

Comment: What have you deleted?. If it's just your system there's little to worry about. But did you wipe out your data files which were not backed up?

Comment: @user68186 Why not write an answer with those two options? Ping me if you do and I'll upvote. Thanks.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Done!

Comment: @user68186 Thanks. Quid Pro Quo.

Comment: @PaulBenson I was running a custom compile script that I use all the time on my codebase in order to automatically compile a bunch of python code into binaries, and remove the source. But I accidentally ran it from the wrong directory and lost my entire code base because I was two stupid to make it exit if it doesn't copy properly to the build folder. The last back up was stored two weeks ago. So it's not a total disaster but I will likely lose my client.....and rightly so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Step 1: Boot from live CD/USB

Use the try Ubuntu without installing option. Plug in the external hard drive. It has to be at least 64GB or bigger.

## Step 2: Identify the disks

Open Gparted. I prefer Gparted because it is visual and let me "see" the drives and partitions.  Click on the top right drop down and see the list of drives. Go through the list and identify the drives you want to work with, by their size and partition structure. You want to identify the internal hard drive you want to clone from as well as the external hard drive you want to copy to.

[image]

## Step 3: Copy partition

Select the partition you you want to copy. Right click on it. From the context menu select copy.

[image]

## Step 4: Paste partition

Select the external hard drive and paste the partition there. It is best if the external hard drive does not have any partitions and or data.

You don't have to create a new partition beforehand in the external hard disk to copy the partition. You will need unformatted / unallocated space in the disk

[image]

**Apply** to actually do the work. Until you press Apply it will look something like this:

[image]

## Done!

## Alternate command line method

## Step 1: Boot from Live USB/DVD as before

## Step 2: Identify the disks and partitions

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
```

You will be asked for your password. When you type the password the cursor will not move and you won't see any `*****`. This is normal.

It would show something like this:

```
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda           111.8G            
├─sda1 swap     121M [SWAP]     
└─sda2 ext4   111.7G /          
sdc             232.8G            
sdd             149.1G            
└─sdd1 ext4     149.1G          original
```

## Step 3: Copy partition (Or the whole drive) using `dd`

### Copy the first partition

As before I assume we want to copy `/dev/sdd1` to `/dev/sdc1`. Make sure the source partition `/dev/sdd1` is unmounted. There should not be any partitions in `/dev/sdc` the destination drive. Your disks and partitions will be different. **Adjust command accordingly**:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdd1 of=/dev/sdc1
```

wait till it is done. It may take a long time. Once it is done you will see the command prompt `$` again.

### Alternately copy the whole drive

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdd of=/dev/sdc
```

This is useful if you have many partitions in the original disk and want to save them all.
Hope this helps

Comment: that is super helpful. I went with the first answer in the comments that came up before I saw this,because I was pressed for time. But I would definately also prefer this method in the future.

Comment: @enemyspy I hope you get all your files back. Best of luck.